# snappydata Unable to access SnappyData store from an Existing Spark Installation using Smart Connector by Java

Tags: java, snappydata

I try to connect to SnappyData store by smart connector style as description in http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/#how-to-access-snappydata-store-from-an-existing-spark-installation-using-smart-connector, but got com.gemstone.gemfire.SerializationException root caused by java.nio.BufferUnderflowException.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.SerializationException: Could not create an instance of  com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.UpdateAttributesProcessor$UpdateAttributesMessage .
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2900)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.create(DSFIDFactory.java:819)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readDSFID(InternalDataSerializer.java:3311)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.processNIOBuffer(Connection.java:3573)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.runNioReader(Connection.java:1840)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.run(Connection.java:1715)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.ReplyException.fixUpRemoteEx(ReplyException.java:109)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.ReplyException.handleAsUnexpected(ReplyException.java:87)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.UpdateAttributesProcessor.waitForProfileResponse(UpdateAttributesProcessor.java:94)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.UpdateAttributesProcessor.distribute(UpdateAttributesProcessor.java:79)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.DistributionAdvisor.exchangeProfiles(DistributionAdvisor.java:1231)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.DistributionAdvisor.initializationGate(DistributionAdvisor.java:485)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.distributed.GfxdDistributionAdvisor.handshake(GfxdDistributionAdvisor.java:235)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.store.GemFireStore$StoreAdvisee.start(GemFireStore.java:2565)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.store.GemFireStore$StoreAdvisee.access$000(GemFireStore.java:2501)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.store.GemFireStore.boot(GemFireStore.java:1208)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:2245)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:314)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(BaseMonitor.java:720)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(FileMonitor.java:65)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Monitor.java:497)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.db.FabricDatabase.bootStore(FabricDatabase.java:2358)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.db.FabricDatabase.boot(FabricDatabase.java:354)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:2245)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:314)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(BaseMonitor.java:2043)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(BaseMonitor.java:1906)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(BaseMonitor.java:1786)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(BaseMonitor.java:1196)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Monitor.java:620)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java:3379)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(EmbedConnection.java:452)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(EmbedConnection30.java:94)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(EmbedConnection40.java:75)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Driver40.java:95)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:351)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:219)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:195)
    at io.snappydata.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(AutoloadedDriver.java:153)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.fabricservice.FabricServiceImpl.startImpl(FabricServiceImpl.java:279)
    at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.fabricservice.FabricServerImpl.start(FabricServerImpl.java:60)
    at io.snappydata.impl.LeadImpl.internalStart(LeadImpl.scala:188)
    at io.snappydata.impl.LeadImpl$.invokeLeadStart(LeadImpl.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SnappyEmbeddedModeClusterManager.initialize(SnappyEmbeddedModeClusterManager.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2506)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at com.meituan.hotel.pegasuscollect.spark.SmartConnectorMain.main(SmartConnectorMain.java:11)
    at com.meituan.hotel.pegasuscollect.controller.SparkController.getCompActualPriceModelFromCache(SparkController.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.SerializationException: Could not create an instance of  com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.distributed.GfxdDistributionAdvisor$GfxdProfile .
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2900)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.readGfxdMessage(DSFIDFactory.java:986)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.create(DSFIDFactory.java:775)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:3424)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.basicReadObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:3417)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readObject(DataSerializer.java:3342)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.UpdateAttributesProcessor$UpdateAttributesMessage.fromData(UpdateAttributesProcessor.java:356)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2887)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.create(DSFIDFactory.java:819)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readDSFID(InternalDataSerializer.java:3311)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.processNIOBuffer(Connection.java:3573)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.runNioReader(Connection.java:1840)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.run(Connection.java:1715)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:506)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getInt(DirectByteBuffer.java:681)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.ByteBufferInputStream.readInt(ByteBufferInputStream.java:190)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readInteger(DataSerializer.java:881)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.distributed.GfxdDistributionAdvisor$GfxdProfile.fromData(GfxdDistributionAdvisor.java:1574)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2887)
    ... 13 more
Caused by:
com.gemstone.gemfire.SerializationException: Could not create an instance of  com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.distributed.GfxdDistributionAdvisor$GfxdProfile .
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2900)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.readGfxdMessage(DSFIDFactory.java:986)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.create(DSFIDFactory.java:775)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:3424)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.basicReadObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:3417)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readObject(DataSerializer.java:3342)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.UpdateAttributesProcessor$UpdateAttributesMessage.fromData(UpdateAttributesProcessor.java:356)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2887)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.create(DSFIDFactory.java:819)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readDSFID(InternalDataSerializer.java:3311)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.processNIOBuffer(Connection.java:3573)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.runNioReader(Connection.java:1840)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.run(Connection.java:1715)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:506)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getInt(DirectByteBuffer.java:681)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.ByteBufferInputStream.readInt(ByteBufferInputStream.java:190)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readInteger(DataSerializer.java:881)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.distributed.GfxdDistributionAdvisor$GfxdProfile.fromData(GfxdDistributionAdvisor.java:1574)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2887)
    ... 13 more
Caused by:
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:506)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getInt(DirectByteBuffer.java:681)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.ByteBufferInputStream.readInt(ByteBufferInputStream.java:190)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readInteger(DataSerializer.java:881)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.distributed.GfxdDistributionAdvisor$GfxdProfile.fromData(GfxdDistributionAdvisor.java:1574)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2887)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.readGfxdMessage(DSFIDFactory.java:986)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.create(DSFIDFactory.java:775)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:3424)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.basicReadObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:3417)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readObject(DataSerializer.java:3342)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.UpdateAttributesProcessor$UpdateAttributesMessage.fromData(UpdateAttributesProcessor.java:356)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeFromData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2887)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.DSFIDFactory.create(DSFIDFactory.java:819)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readDSFID(InternalDataSerializer.java:3311)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.processNIOBuffer(Connection.java:3573)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.runNioReader(Connection.java:1840)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.Connection.run(Connection.java:1715)
    at Remote Member 'host-07(41099)<v7>:32671' in java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the code:

```
public class SmartConnectorMain{
public static void main(String [] args){

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("SmartConnectorMainJava")
            .master("snappydata://host-01:9999,host05-:9999")
            .config("snappydata.store.locators", "host-01:9999,host-05:9999")
            .getOrCreate();

    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
    SnappySession snappy = new SnappySession(spark.sparkContext());

    println(" ####  Creating a table TestColumnTable  #### \n");

    snappy.dropTable("TestColumnTable",  true);

    DataSet<Row> dataFrame = snappy.range(1000).selectExpr("id", "floor(rand() * 10000) as k");

    snappy.sql("create table TestColumnTable (id bigint not null, k bigint not null) using column");


    println(" ####  Write to table completed. ### \n\n" +
            "Now you can query table TestColumnTable using $SNAPPY_HOME/bin/snappy-shell");
}

private static void println(String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

And here is the configuration in cluster:

```
Name    Value
jobserver.enabled   true
snappydata.embedded true
snappydata.store.critical-heap-percentage   90.0
snappydata.store.eviction-heap-percentage   81.0
snappydata.store.host-data  true
snappydata.store.locators   host-01:9999,host-05:9999
snappydata.store.log-file   snappyleader.log
snappydata.store.mcast-port 0
snappydata.store.statistic-archive-file snappyleader.gfs
spark.app.id    snappy-app-1494920649221
spark.app.name  leaderLauncher
spark.closure.serializer    org.apache.spark.serializer.PooledKryoSerializer
spark.driver.host   10.16.118.36
spark.driver.port   25490
spark.executor.cores    10
spark.executor.id   driver
spark.master    snappydata://host-01:9999,host-05:9999
spark.scheduler.mode    FAIR
spark.serializer    org.apache.spark.serializer.PooledKryoSerializer
spark.ui.port   9411
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your SnappyData locators and Spark master URL is using the same host and port. I quickly verified with SnappyData 0.8 version, with Spark2.0 local mode cluster using spark package 0.8-s_2.11 from https://spark-packages.org/package/SnappyDataInc/snappydata.

I was able to query the table through snappy-sql shell as well. 
Here is screenshot of my program [image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. One difference here from my code  is that master is "local", but not a remote cluster, will this cause the issue?

Comment: Does the different master configuration, local or remote address,  cause different test result?

Comment: I mean, the spark driver will be in different hosts with the spark master.